# How can I present the posted on date parameter from credit adjustments across individual columns for each date, based on customer

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

In the report I'm working on ,user enters from date and to date i.e. **credit limit adjustments posted on** dates. I want the dates entered to show up in different columns for based on the customer account in the SSRS report.
[Here it shows how the report should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLLTE.png)

I am not able to figure out where i should give the condition for that